# Stacked column chart based on 2 variables using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stacked **column** chart in R using ggplot2. here is my data:

```
    procedure          mh_avg_charge avg_duration bench_avg bench_sd   mh_z mh_perc
1 Colonoscopy with ~          4905           37     6253.    1508. -0.894   0.268
2 Colonoscopy with ~          5099           38     6778.    1561. -1.08    0.224
3 Upper Gastrointes~          3845           30     5356.    1572. -0.962   0.251
4 Upper Gastrointes~          5374           40     7159.    2035. -0.877   0.272
```

I would like the x-axis to be `procedure` and have stacked columns of `mh_avg_charge` and `bench_avg`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
gi_pt_summary %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = procedure)) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(y = mh_avg_charge),
           fill = "steelblue")+
  geom_col(mapping = aes(y = bench_avg),
           fill = "orangered3")
```

I am looking to recreate this graph that I made separately in Excel.
[image]

But with my R code I am getting this:
[image]

I cannot find any docs or questions answered that address the problem of doing stacked columns based on observations of a variable, not `count`.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

Reshape before plotting, so you can map `fill` to a variable, i.e.:

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(gi_pt_summary, c('mh_avg_charge', 'bench_avg'), names_to = 'variable') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(procedure, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack')
```